# How do adversary models and security types relate [from InfoSec SE]

Tags: security-definition, adversarial-model

I have been told to move the question to this forum in order to get a better insight, so here we go:

Reading some questions in this forum I encountered [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117293/the-requirements-of-a-cryptographic-algorithm/117295#117295) mentioning IND-CPA as a requirement for ciphers. It got me thinking about [this paper](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/andrew.paverd/casper/casper-privacy-report.pdf) I recently read, where a formal model of the Honest-But-Curious adversary is given, in order to automate the analysis of whether certain protocol has the indistinguishability property. And I have this way realized I am missing a piece in the puzzle.

As far as I remember, in a Cryptographic System, we have:

**Attacks** like

- Ciphertext-only (Passive Attack)
- Known Plaintext Attack (Passive Attack)
- Chosen Plaintext Attack (CPA)
- Chosen Ciphertext Attack (CCA)

And **Notions of Security** like

- Semantic Security (SS, SEM)
- Indistinguishability Security (IND)
- Non-malleability (NM)

And for stating the **notions** preserved under certain **attacks** we end up with combinations like the well known **IND-CPA**.

Now, how do adversarial models like *Dolev-Yao*, *Honest-But-Curious* or *Byzantine* fit in this scheme? ( If they do at all and I am not mixing up things)

Comment: You are mixing up a lot of things. Get a good textbook.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @fkraiem what exactly am I mixing up according to you? I have been reading quite a bit and I cannot see anything wrong in my question so far...